# Matplotlib convert an array to a 1 chart line

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, data-visualization, visualization

I have a lists that I want to convert to a line chart graph, the results I get are very chaotic, the list contain negative and positive values.

my code:

```
macd = []
signals = []

for i in data['Technical Analysis: MACD'].values():
    macd.insert(len(macd), i['MACD'])
    signals.insert(len(signals), i['MACD_Signal'])

plt.plot(macd)
plt.plot(signals)
plt.show()
```

Here what I get:
[image]

data example:

```
macd = ['-0.0099', '-0.0108', '-0.0091', '-0.0074', '-0.0052', '-0.0002', '0.0032', '0.0064', '0.0083', '0.0107', '0.0106', '0.0102', '0.0126', '0.0145', '0.0137', '0.0114', '0.0093', '0.0055', '-0.0005', '-0.0070', '-0.0082', '-0.0116', '-0.0137', '-0.0152', '-0.0159', '-0.0175', '-0.0184', '-0.0191', '-0.0199', '-0.0205', '-0.0210', '-0.0214', '-0.0205', '-0.0191', '-0.0170', '-0.0161', '-0.0148', '-0.0118', '-0.0089', '-0.0091', '-0.0082', '-0.0070', '-0.0073', '-0.0076', '-0.0069', '-0.0064', '-0.0062', '-0.0048', '-0.0039', '-0.0028']

signals = ['-0.0042', '-0.0028', '-0.0008', '0.0012', '0.0034', '0.0056', '0.0070', '0.0079', '0.0083', '0.0083', '0.0077', '0.0070', '0.0062', '0.0046', '0.0021', '-0.0008', '-0.0038', '-0.0071', '-0.0102', '-0.0127', '-0.0141', '-0.0156', '-0.0165', '-0.0173', '-0.0178', '-0.0182', '-0.0184', '-0.0184', '-0.0182', '-0.0178', '-0.0172', '-0.0162', '-0.0149', '-0.0135', '-0.0121', '-0.0109', '-0.0096', '-0.0083', '-0.0074', '-0.0070', '-0.0065', '-0.0061', '-0.0059', '-0.0055', '-0.0050', '-0.0045', '-0.0041', '-0.0036', '-0.0033', '-0.0031']
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of the data?

Comment: I provided some examples in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Values in your data are `str`, you need to convert them in number type like `float` before plotting:

```
macd = list(map(float, macd))
signals = list(map(float, signals))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I really feel stupid for not noticing that.

Comment: @AdamDemo_Fighter that's why it is always better to provide a minimal example ;)